# How to find the complexity of the following loop

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

What would be the worst case running time of the following code where the input is 2 variables and loop exits when first variable becomes larger than the second one. My first guess was O(1) considering (x raised to 3) scales pretty quickly compared to (x raised to 2) but i don't know if it does close the gap quickly even when a is 1 and b is very very large integer.

```
i = 0;
cin >> a >> b;

while (a <= b)
{
  i++;
  a *= 3; b*= 2;
}

cout << i;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are solving for the equation:

[image: Equation]

So solving for n, you get:

[image: Solution]

Assuming that b > a > 1.

Even for large differences, where a = 1.0001 and b = 10^1000, you get a small `n = 41.8`